# Unable to get Broadcom wireless drivers working on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers, configuration, broadcom

I am trying to get Wifi working on my Arch Linux installation so I have installed `broadcom-wl-dkms`, but it still does not seem to work. I noticed that one every startup I got this message:

```
Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1
```

So I enabled them as it said, but still the Wifi doesn't work.

During the `broadcom-wl-dkms` installation I was told to run the following commands or reboot (neither worked):

```
rmmod b43 b43legacy ssb bcm43xx brcm80211 brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma wl
modprobe wl
```

Upon running the first one I got this output:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module b43legacy is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module bcm43xx is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcm80211 is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcmfmac is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module wl is not currently loaded
```

And the second gave this output:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.11.0-1-hardened
```

I have also noticed that on Kernel updates I get messages like this:

```
==> dkms remove broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271 -k 4.11.0-1-hardened
Error! There is no instance of broadcom-wl 6.30.223.271
for kernel 4.11.0-1-hardened (x86_64) located in the DKMS tree.
```

And this:

```
==> dkms install broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271 -k 4.11.0-2-hardened
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.11.0-2-hardened (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271/build/make.log for more information.
```

So I assume that something has gone wrong. What has gone wrong? And how can I fix this and get the Wifi working?

This is a Lenovo B590 laptop.

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg | grep b43`?  If you don't have a device with core revision 0x17 or 0x18, there is no reason to enable those revisions

Comment: @Fox: I have updated my question with the information you requested.

Comment: Have you tried the `broadcom-wl` driver instead?  (It seems to be newer and better supported, and from the contents you show, it looks like you _might_ have one of those two disabled revisions)

Comment: @Fox: No, but I have been trying to have a go with `broadcom-wl-dkms` as I generally don't trust things in the AUR.

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be going very well as it hasn't made any real difference other than the Wireless section has disappeared from the gnome-control-center.

Comment: You might _try_ adding `b43.conf` to `/etc/modprobe.d/` containing `options b43 allhwsupport=1` (as requested by the warning) to see if that helps any

Comment: @Fox: I will give that a go and then let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Fox: I've done that and restarted the system, but apart from the messages being gone at startup, there is no other immediately noticeable change. For instance, no wifi section still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58322/discussion-between-fox-and-paranoid-panda).

Comment: @Fox: Right, I have messaged you in there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP has a Broadcom BCM4313 chipset, which is not supported by the `b43` driver, so enabling the core revisions listed in the warning will have no effect.  Further, this particular chipset is not fully supported by the `brcmsmac` driver, leaving only Broadcom's own (restrictively-licensed) `broadcom-wl` driver, specifically the `broadcom-wl-dkms` variant.

However, at the time the Q was posted, the `broadcom-wl` driver (at least in the Arch repositories) was not yet updated to support kernels 4.11-rc1 or later.  These newer kernels changed a bit of the interface to network devices, including removing the `last_rx` field from `struct net_device`.

As of 10 May 2017, version 6.30.223.271-12 of the `broadcom-wl-dkms` driver was made available through these repositories, allowing compilation against the 4.11 series kernels.