# Broadcom Wireless PCI Card BMC4360 14e4:43a0 cannot get drivers working

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers, configuration, broadcom

I have a problem similar to this:

[Unable to get Broadcom wireless drivers working on Arch Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363409)

But in my case, loading the broadcom-wl-dkms driver did not work. I am new to this, so maybe the solution is quite simple (hopefully). 
What I did so far: 
I installed various drivers with yaourt and pacman, ending up with the broadcom-wl-dkms driver. 
When I list the available internet devices with `ip link` I still only get two results, the lo and the chipset of my motherboard (where the LAN´s plugged in and works just fine). 
With `lsmod` I thought I would get a list of all active drivers, but the broadcom-wl-dkms is not shown there.

What do I have to do in order to get the drivers all set up and running?

Ah, running `wifi-menu` gives me returns in bright red *INVALID INTERFACE SPECIFICATIONS* but I'm guessing that's just because it can't see any wireless networking devices.

I read quite a lot of posts but nothing really helped so far (And yes, I checked the Arch Wiki beforehand). 
Does it have something to do with the driver being restrictively licensed drivers?

Output of `lspci -knn | grep net -A2` :

> 00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet
>   Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)    Subsystem: Micro-Star
>   International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
>   [1462:7a12]   Kernel driver in use: e1000e    Kernel modules: e1000e

Fascinating: output of `lspci -knn|grep Net -A2`:

> 07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless
>   Network Adapter (rev 03)

Running `lsmod | grep wl` produces no result. How do I load the driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working.

My working environment: 4.16.5-1-ARCH [`rname -r`]

My Desktop: GNOME

My Network-Env.: network-manager-applet 1.8.11dev+12+ga37483c1-1

My Wlan-Card: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] [`lspci -vnn -d 14e4:`]

What I did: 
I looked at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices[/url:2j8cyqph] to find compatible drivers, which in my case turned out to be none but the wl package (install with `pacman -S broadcom-wl`). Make sure everything is up-to-date with `sudo pacman -Sy`, after that make sure your filesystem is all good with `sudo pacman filesystem linux` (which it wasn't in my case ;)). Check if your systems version `uname -r && pacman -Q linux`.  Reboot. This already solved it, as the new kernel update brought some changes to

> b43-firmware  broadcom-wl  nvidia

```
rmmod b43 b43legacy bcm43xx bcma brcm80211 brcmfmac brcmsmac ssb wl 117    
modprobe wl
```

***did change nothing for me***, but you can try /(as mentioned in the wiki ->https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless)

You might have to restart Network Manager: `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`
What might have helped was installing linux headers: `sudo pacman -S linux-headers`

I don't know for sure what changed it to working, I guess it was the kernel update.

Comment: I have Broadcom BCM43142 chip and I can verify that the above approach works. @T.m Chronos, many thanks!