# Arch Linux BCM4360

Tags: linux, wifi, manjaro

Hello I have been trying to use Manjaro Linux on my MacBook Air 2017. Everything is working fine except the WiFi driver for the BCM4360.
A little info:

- Linux Kernel: 5.6.15
- Linux distro: Manjaro
- WiFi driver: linux56-Broadcom-wl
  Problem:
  Whenever I try to run:

  modprobe wl

I get this error:

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert ‘wl’: invalid argument.

Tutorials i have already tried:

[Broadcom Wireless PCI Card BMC4360 14e4:43a0 cannot get drivers working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440143/broadcom-wireless-pci-card-bmc4360-14e443a0-cannot-get-drivers-working)

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/broadcom-bcm4360-not-working/47060

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Wireless communication** features **can be disabled on a hardware level**.
   It is toggled by pressing `Fn+PrtScr` (next to `F12`). Check it out.
2. As far as I know, `BCMA` is **blacklisted** because it causes problems having it running with `broadcom-wl`. If you want to try it, uninstall `linux38-broadcom-wl` (`BCMA` is automatically **unblacklisted**).
3. **Rebuild** `broadcom-wl` and **reboot**. (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg#Usage)
4. Try to **install** moduls: `sudo modprobe -a bcma wl`.
5. Try to **delete** from blacklist last two lines: `blacklist brcmsmac` `blacklist bcma`

   After that check output of this command: `lspci -k | grep -i -A3 wi`.

   If it does not help, then add the line to that file: `blacklist wl`